# 415 unsupported format while passing json to java

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-mvc

I need to pass an object from JavaScript to a Java Controller. I am doing it as follows:

```
//java code
@RequestMapping(value="/mailsend" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public int getBranchById(@RequestBody Modelmail details) throws IOException{
System.out.println(details);
```

following is the javascript code

```
 submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }

        var details={"name":name,"email":email,"phone":phone,"message":message}
        //var obj = JSON.parse(details);
        $.ajax({
            url: "./mailsend",
            type: "POST",
            data: details,
            cache: false,
            success: function() {

    }}
```

Even I have added the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I am not getting the Java object in Java as per my expectations. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your ajax function will not send json string it will send formdata,To send your data as json string you need to convert it to json string JSON.stringify().

Comment: try what the comment above says, also adding a dataType: 'json' to the ajax  query would be nice, to specify what are you sending in headers

Comment: data: JSON.stringify(details),
  dataType: 'json',    i have added these two things but still the same

Comment: @user3273700 you are right its sending data as formdata rather it should send it as a payload i guess how to achieve that??

Comment: can you upate your Modelmail class?

Comment: You can also add 'consumes = "application/json"' to your controllers request mapping. With this and on the frontend side Stringifying the object to JSON you might be ok. Without more log info, it's a bit difficult to debug.

Comment: @kuhajeyan Modelmail class is perfect with all the fields and setters getters and constructor using all fields

Comment: are you sure that {"name":name,"email":email,"phone":phone,"message":message} consists  all fields except that are marked @jsonIgnore

Comment: public class Modelmail {
private String name;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String message; //these fields with setter getter and construcror
}

Comment: can you annotate your method with  @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) or with 

@RequestMapping(value = "/mainsend", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

and try

Answer (score 0):

To fix 4xx unsupported media, you can activate Spring logs by setting the following line to your app.properties:

```
log4j.category.org.springframework=ALL
```

After activating the Spring logs, make the related request again and check the log output to see where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ajax call to include content type headers, and stringfy your data

```
 $.ajax({
    headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
                url: './mailsend',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(details),
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function() {

        }
}
```